# Python. Unzip archive to which the filenames are encoded using urlencode, and because of the encoding, the length of some names is > 260

Tags: python, zip, byte, python-zipfile

Creating a backend on FastApi. Post request, the bytes string is received. After that, I create a zip archive from this line. But the file names are encoded using url encoding.

data: bytes - bytes строка

```
with open("name.zip", 'wb') as f:
f.write(data)
```

I will get these File names > 260 characters, which is why the archive is not unpacked
[File names > 260 characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWPV4.png)

I tried to look for bad names, decode them and replace them in a byte string with the correct ones.
After that, the archive is destroyed.

As I know, you cannot change the names inside the archive.
I can't figure out how to solve this problem.

Comment: How are you getting the data? If you're reading the raw post data, you need to decode it. You should use middleware like Flask, which will decode parameters for you.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry for how to remove the limit.